Numbers: If string in one column matches string in another column value = a third column value
I am not sure how to set up this conditional. Say I have a table like so:



Animal
Totals




Cat
10


Dog
6


Cow
4



and a second table like so:



Type
Type Total
Animal
Animal Total




Black
5
Cat
XX


Retriever
3
Dog
XX


Brown
2
Cow
XX


Calico
5
Cat
XX


Hound
3
Dog
XX


Oreo
2
Cow
XX



What I am trying to write a formula for is:
If a cell value in Table 2, Col C (Animal) matches a cell value in Table 1, Col A (also Animal) populate the corresponding cell in Table 2, Col D (Animal Total) with the value from Table 1, Col B (Totals). I'm not sure how to structure that formula.

I solved the issue by using VLOOKUP. Posting here so it can be referenced by anyone else:
Formula: (place in Animal Total cells).
VLOOKUP($C1, Table 1::$A:$B, 2)
Explanation
VLOOKUP will take a search term, search for it in the search range of columns (V = vertical, if you wanted to do rows use HLOOKUP (horizontal)), and return the value from the cell in a designated column:
Above, our search term will be the value in $C1 of the table the formula is in, in this case, "Cat".
The search range covers the entire first table. You could tweak this to include just one column or a series of columns.
The return result will be the value of the second cell in the second column of the range for the row a match was found in. So in this case "10", since the match of "Cat" was found in the first row, and column B is the second column in the range supplied.
You could also wrap this in an IFERROR check and return a default value if you are not confident there will be a match.
The formula will return the closest matching value if you do not explicitly ask for a True or False return.
Full Apple documentation is available at Formulas and Functions Help: VLOOKUP
